# How to configure intelliJ test runner framework

Tags: testing, intellij-idea

How can I configure different test runners for different folders in my project?
For example I have jest unit tests and in other folder I have playwright e2e testcases.

Right now IntelliJ tries to run playwright e2e test as Karma testcases.

Answer (score 1):

The logic currently used by **JavaScript support** plugin for detecting what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json` nearest to this file: it looks for known test runners listed there and tries to run the most suitable one
Unfortunately there is no way to choose a test runner explicitly; if you miss this feature, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28397

Comment: What should the package.json contain to IntelliJ use playwright instead of Karma?

What if there are multiple test frameworks?